# aiohttp inconsistent await behavior for different content types

Tags: aiohttp

I am trying to write a server that can pass a long a request for me, get the response to that request, then return me the response.

What I'm running into is that response bodies seem to be handled differently on the await of the response's body depending on whether it's text or a file.

Example:

```py
async def retransmit_GET(self,path):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(path) as resp:
      headers = ParseMultiDict(resp.headers) #convert MultiDictProxy to a simple dictionary

      if headers['Content-Type'] not 'application/json':
        #THIS DOESN'T WORK
        #await resp.content.read()
        #return resp
        #THIS DOES WORK
        file_content = await resp.content.read()
        return web.Response(body=file_content, status=resp.status, headers=headers)
      else:
        await resp.text()
        return resp

async def receive_GET(self, request):
  try:
    result = await self.retransmit_GET(self,request.rel_url.path)
    headers = ParseMultiDict(result.headers)
    if headers['Content-Type'] not 'application/json':
      #### THIS IS THE LINE THAT WILL THROW THE EXCEPTION
      return web.Response(body=result.content.read(), status=result.status, headers=headers)
    else:
      return web.Response(text=await result.text(), status=result.status, headers=headers)
  except Exception as e:
    print('EXCEPTION:", e)
```

Why can I await the body in the case of text() and then the body is passed correctly, but when I do the same with the content without creating a new object it simply returns me "EXCEPTION: Connection closed" on trying to read resp.content outside of this function?